# In Android how it is possible to override onWindowVisibilityChanged for all the views inside a Dialog without having to override each one?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have a Dialog (Presentation) with multiple views (GLSurfaceView, ImageView,...) and I want to avoid all the views to receive the onWindowVisibilityChanged event when the main activity is minimized so I can keep them visible in the second screen. I can override onWindowVisibilityChanged for each view (so the views never see visibility = GONE) but I would prefer a more elegant way to do it by preventing any view in the Dialog to have their onWindowVisibilityChanged called with visibility = GONE. Other creative options are welcome.

Is it possible? How?

This is the code I currently have to do in every view so they ignore the View.GONE value. Ideally I would do it at a central place that would avoid the dispatch calls or that would call the children with View.VISIBLE:

```
@Override
protected void onWindowVisibilityChanged(int visibility) {
    super.onWindowVisibilityChanged(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code snippets you have tried yet.

Comment: Thanks, the code is simple, I am trying to avoid the nasty duplication by taking advantage of hierarchy.

Comment: Simple use inheritance and when you set visibility to your dialog object you will receive the onWindowVisibilityChanged callback in your Super Class